# Saving and restoring image in a view *without* using a nav controller?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uinavigationcontroller, push, segue

I'm writing an OpenGL app which draws trails/strokes by not clearing the frame buffer from frame to frame (it just lets everything accumulate on top of itself, which is what I want).

The app has a Settings screen.  You access it by tapping a button.  After you're done with the settings, it returns to the graphics.

Here's the problem:  I can't figure out how to transition from the settings back to the graphics without losing what was in the frame buffer.  The app is sort of a painting toy. You'd like to be able to paint, go to the settings, and then return to what you were doing without the screen clearing and deleting your work!

If I used a NavigationController all of this would be taken care of (I've tried it -- works perfectly!)

Problem is, I don't want the ugly, bulky nav bar thing on the top of my screen. But, you have to take the nav bar if you want the nav controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is simple.  Hide the navigation bar.

```
navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

See here:

[UINavigationController without navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765946/uinavigationcontroller-without-navigation-bar)

Comment: If you hide the nav bar, you hide the button on it as well;  you can't do a push segue without using the nav bar.

If there was a way use a custom image for the bar and button, that would work.  I could just make the bar invisible, and use my own button.  But, I don't think you can customize the nav bar.

Comment: Yes, you can customize it. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Comment: No, you can't customize it in the way I described.  You can change the color and transparency and what not, but you can't make it invisible.

Let me explain it again:  One way to solve the problem I mention (there are hopefully other ways, too) is to use a Navigation Controller.  But, Navigation Controller requires using a Navigation Bar to move between views.  But, I don't want to see the Navigation Bar.  There is no way to use, say, custom button icons and a custom background image to make it appear in a way which would fit my app. So, that's probably not going to work.

Comment: If it were me I would hide the navigation bar, put your custom button on top of the view and have the button invoke your navigation controller manually.  I guess you could go the hard route and copy the pixels into memory, use your manual navigation method and then re-copy them to the screen once the user returns from the settings view.

Comment: Yes, I tried the hard route, but I couldn't get it to work.  Drawing an EAGLayer to a bitmap context doesn't seem to be supported.  I'll try your other idea.

Answer (score 0):

Before you leave to go to the settings, save what's in the framebuffer with glReadPixels. When you return, load that data into a texture and draw it on the screen.