# Hiding UINavigationBar in a UIView under Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6

Running XCode 4.6 and I'm using Storyboarding. 
I'm fairly new to iOS (started with 4.5).

I've got a Navigation Controller in my storyboard leading to a few UITableViewController's which leads to a UIView(Controller).

I'd like to hide/disclose the UINavigationBar that is automatically added to the UIView from the Navigation Controller - if at all possible?

I know how to do this when I have an IBOutlet UINavigationBar outlet
e.g. navBar.hidden = true;

The Connections Inspector for the Nav Bar in the UIView shows that I have only the UINavigationItem and not the UINavigationBar to reference.

1) Is it possible to hide the UINavigationBar when using a Navigation Controller with UIView?
2) How can I do this programatically (or rather where do I reference the automatically added UINavigationBar from within any Navigation Controller controlled sub-view? )

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5765994/620197

Comment: Mike, you are a gentleman. Thanks! This was what I was looking for `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UINavigationController without navigation bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765946/uinavigationcontroller-without-navigation-bar)